# Number picker is freezing the app - why so?

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I am creating a **NumberPicker** with horizontal orientation which is freezing my app. Initial state is that the picker is not visible. In a method I set it visible and push data into it

```
        if (_regalPicker != null) {
        _regalPicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String[] templist = new String[arr.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            templist[i] = arr.get(i).name;
        }
        _regalPicker.setDisplayedValues(null);
        _regalPicker.setMinValue(0);
        _regalPicker.setMaxValue(templist.length - 1);
        _regalPicker.setDisplayedValues(templist);
        _regalPicker.setValue(1);
        _regalPicker.setEnabled(true);
        _regalPicker.setFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        _regalPicker.setScrollerEnabled(true);
        _regalPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        _regalPicker.invalidate();
    }
```

It updates the **Strings** but I am not able to scroll it anymore. Any ideas?
My dividers are also not getting updated.

Comment: Your context is not clear. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you exactly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your ui without freezing your app with a thread

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
       public void run(){

            String[] templist = new String[arr.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                        templist[i] = arr.get(i).name;
                    }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    // change UI elements here
                    if (_regalPicker != null) {
                        _regalPicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        _regalPicker.setDisplayedValues(null);
                        _regalPicker.setMinValue(0);
                        _regalPicker.setMaxValue(templist.length - 1);
                        _regalPicker.setDisplayedValues(templist);
                        _regalPicker.setValue(1);
                        _regalPicker.setEnabled(true);
                        _regalPicker.setFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
                        _regalPicker.setScrollerEnabled(true);
                        _regalPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
                        _regalPicker.invalidate();
                  }

                }
            });

       }
    }        
thread.start();
```

Comment: still not changing...my layout gets refreshed, but i cant click or scroll in the picker

Comment: @Damaro Oh sorry i did not notice the end of your question ... You should show more code with your XML layout